# jQuery TableSorter difficult sort not working

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

The table has a couple of columns including the first column containing custom Date format (dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS) 
e.g

```
   <tr>
        <td>14-05-2012 13:57:04</td>
        <td>MTUPTTC01V4.3_E2E-LoadBalancer-1336992891.jtl</td>
        <td>14-05-2012 13:10:03</td>
        <td>14-05-2012 13:56:38</td>
        <td>00:46:35</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>152328</td>
        <td>2494</td>
        <td>1.64%</td>
        <td><a href="2012-05-14_13_56_52">Results</a></td>
    </tr>
```

and i am using the following custom parser but it doesnt seem to work.

```
   $.tablesorter.addParser({
                id: 'jmeterDate',
                is: function(s) {
                        return false;
                },
                format: function(s) {
                        var date = s.match(/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})[ ](\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/);
                        var d = date[1];
                        var m = date[2];
                        var y = date[3];
                        var H = date[4];
                        var M = date[5];
                        var S = date[6];
                        var MS = 0;
                        //return '' + y + m + d;
                        return new Date(y, m, d, H, M, S, MS).getTime();
                },
                type: 'Numeric'
        });
        $("#tablesorter-table").tablesorter({
                headers: {
                        0: {
                                sorter: 'jmeterDate'
                        }
                }
        });
```

See the following link for a complete example

http://jsfiddle.net/Ese5A/1/

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.js - gives 404

Comment: Ye but in my app I am hosting the jQuery lib on apache (app doesn't have access to open web ) and its loading the lib fine so that's not the problem, and I can confirm that sorting by normal text is working but I need the above mentioned custom format for the date and sorted in ascending order with latest date being at the top

Comment: Well, the jsfiddle isn't working because of that. That doesn't help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, it wasn't the jQuery or the custom tablesorter, it was actually the Table content itself. length of some of the dates was not what was expected by the regex e.g

04-05-2012 13:7:1

Notice the 7 and the 1, the regex below expects atleast 2 digits.

s.match(/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) :(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/)

FIX:

s.match(/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4}) :(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})$/)

It now accepts digits with length of 1 or 2